# Editing the file "config.inc.php"

Tags: xampp

I put my password into he **config.inc.php** file because I couldn’t access **phpmyadmin** in xampp server. But after editing the file, I can' save it.

Error

> "You do not have the permissions necessary to save the file. Please
>   check that you typed the location correctly and try again."

how can i get rid of this?

Answer (score 3):

Please Open Same File With Sudo Permission
Go to that perticular Directory via terminal
after that edit file by

> sudo nano config.inc.php

or just

> sudo nano /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
>
> Enter Password

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna go through this. This might be the solution you are looking for.
http://blog.elijaa.org/index.php?post/2013/02/19/Solve-Wrong-permissions-on-configuration-file%2C-should-not-be-world-writable!-error-on-phpMyAdmin

Answer (score -2):

```
$ cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/myapp

$ chown bitnami.root config/myapp.php
```